# Create the array of arrays with images asynchronously

Tags: ios, objective-c, arrays, grand-central-dispatch

I need to download the images in matrix (2d array) columns are arrays and every array is consist of the image objects. The problem is that I need to download all this images asynchronously. So now I have:

```
NSMutableArray *sideArray = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:columnCount];
for (int i = 0; i < columnCount; i++) {
    [sideArray addObject:[NSNull null]];
}

NSMutableArray *rowArray = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:rowCount];
for (int i = 0; i < rowCount; i++) {
    [rowArray addObject:[NSNull null]];
}

for (int columnIndex = 0; columnIndex < columnCount; columnIndex++) {
    for (int rowIndex = 0; rowIndex < rowCount; rowIndex++) {

        dispatch_group_enter(group);

        [NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest: request queue: [NSOperationQueue mainQueue] completionHandler:
         ^(NSURLResponse *response, NSData *data, NSError *connectionError)
         {
             if (data.length && nil == connectionError)
             {
                 UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithData:data];
                 [rowArray replaceObjectAtIndex:rowIndex withObject:image];
             }
             dispatch_group_leave(group);
         }];
    }
    [sideArray replaceObjectAtIndex:columnIndex withObject:rowArray];
}
```

Now this method works wrong because of `[sideArray replaceObjectAtIndex:columnIndex withObject:rowArray];` calls not after the all images in group are downloaded. Can't find the correct solution.. any help?

Comment: `[sideArray replaceObjectAtIndex:columnIndex withObject:rowArray];` is not in the completionHandler, so the code will just keep executing after the asynchronous request. The completionHandler however fires later, when the response of the request comes in.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your array setup is incorrect. Just use one array:

```
NSMutableArray *matrixArray = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:rowCount * columnCount];
for (int i = 0; i < rowCount * columnCount; i++) {
    [matrixArray addObject:[NSNull null]];
}

for (int columnIndex = 0; columnIndex < columnCount; columnIndex++) {
    for (int rowIndex = 0; rowIndex < rowCount; rowIndex++) {
        [NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest: request queue: [NSOperationQueue mainQueue] completionHandler:
         ^(NSURLResponse *response, NSData *data, NSError *connectionError)
         {
             if (data.length && nil == connectionError)
             {
                 UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithData:data];
                 [matrixArray replaceObjectAtIndex:rowIndex * columnCount + columnIndex withObject:image];
             }
         }];
    }
}
```

To access an image from the array, use `rowIndex * columnCount + columnIndex`.